# C++ RAII and polymorphism compatibility

Tags: c++, raii

There is no finally block in C++ because of RAII. Now if I have a pointer object and exception happens in one of the method, how this object will be deleted?. Here is a sample code I have written.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"I am inside A\n";
    }

    virtual void mymethod()
    {
        throw 0;
    }

    virtual ~A()
    {
        cout<<"A destroyed\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public :
    //A a;

    B()
    {
        cout<<"I am inside B \n";
    }

    virtual void mymethod()
    {
        throw 0;
    }

    ~B()
    {
        cout<<"B destroyed\n";
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        A *b = new B();

        b->mymethod();

        delete b;
    }

    catch (int i)
    {
        cout<<"exception";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now in this how to delete the pointer object (b).

Comment: What about `unique_ptr<A>`? Also `A` destructor should be virtual.

Comment: There's no need to write "new B()" when you can write = std::make_unique<B>(); and let it clean itself up (no need for delete b then either).

Comment: Well in this example there is no need for `new` either. Just `B b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, all polymorphic types should have [virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). 
Second, when you use owning raw pointers, you basically disable RAII. 
The solution is to use a smart-pointer:

- If you want a unique asset, 
  use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). This wont be copyable.
- If you want a shared asset, 
  use [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). This will do shallow copy.
- If you want value-semantics, 
  use `clone_ptr`. This will do deep copy. 
  It's from the next standard, but 
  you can find it [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3339.pdf)

Comment: That proposal looks very preliminary.

Answer (score 3):

It won't. You're *not using RAII*. Use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The point of RAII is to use variables with automatic storage duration to achieve exception-safety. You could use a smart pointer if you need an object of dynamic storage duration, or you could simply create an object with automatic storage duration to begin with:

```
try
{
    B bobj;
    A *b = &bobj;

    b->mymethod();

}

catch (int i)
{
    cout<<"exception";
}
```

When the stack is unwound because of an exception, all variables with automatic storage duration are properly destroyed, so the smart pointer can deallocate the object in its destructor, and in this example here the object `bobj` would also be destroyed as it should.